# Useful Sites for Ubuntu Offline User?

Tags: package-management, offline

I want to know useful site for offline user who there is know Internet connection but they use Ubuntu. I mean the site to download offline software packages.

Comment: i'm not sure that I understand your question - but does this Q&A help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106183/stand-alone-package-from-ubuntu-repository/

Answer (score 0):

*here is the incomplete list for downloading linux softwares*

1. [softpedia](http://linux.softpedia.com/)
2. [linuxsoft](http://www.linuxsoft.cz/en/)
3. [linux.com](https://www.linux.com/directory)
4. [brother soft](http://www.brothersoft.com/downloads/ubuntu-software.html)

But keep in mind that

> packaging system in ubuntu is much different from windows

*Disclaimer*

i dont know whether i can trust it or not :)